# How to Bind Json Data into Mpandroid Bar Chart in Android?

Tags: java, android

Json Data:

```
[
{
  "NAME":"601 GRIETA EN CUERPO",
  "PERCENTAGE":"46"
},
{
  "NAME":"77 ENFRIAMIENTO O DUNTING",
  "PERCENTAGE":"18"
},
{
  "NAME":"78 PRECALENTAMIENTO",
  "PERCENTAGE":"18"
},
{
  "NAME":"209 MAL MANEJO",
  "PERCENTAGE":"9"
},
{
  "NAME":"92 FUGA DE MANOMETRO",
  "PERCENTAGE":"9"
}
]
```

Bar Chart.Java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class barchart extends AppCompatActivity  {

    BarChart chart ;
    ArrayList<BarEntry> BARENTRY ;
    ArrayList<String> BarEntryLabels ;
    BarDataSet Bardataset ;
    BarData BARDATA ;

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
 private static String url = "http://113.193.30.155/MobileService/MobileService.asmx/GetSampleData";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bar_chart);

new GetContacts().execute();

//        bar chart

        chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barchart);
}
 private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(barchart.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);

                        String NAME = object.getString("NAME");
                        String PERCENTAGE = object.getString("PERCENTAGE");




                    }

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();


        }

    }

}
```

Help me to bind `JSON` data into bar chart in android. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you read the API and figure it out? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i can bind data to bar chart using raw code. But to bind json data from webservice ino mpandroid bar chart am struck. i dont know how to do it. i google it. but nothing found. help me out

Comment: Raw code is not much different than after you parsed the JSON, please show what you've attempted after `object.getString("PERCENTAGE");`